# how to create login module using membership in mvc c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, membership

Hello i have create one project in mvc c#. in this project i have first login module is done with simple code.like click on login and check credenatial in database. but now i want to change my code and doing login module using membership. but in existing project how can change my code i have not idea.

This is my controller method for login =>

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(UsersModel User)
{       
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Users objUser = new Users();
        var res = objUser.Login(User.UserName, User.Password);
        if (res)
        {                        
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {                       
              ErrorMessage = "Login faild";
            ModelState.AddModelError("Error", ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
    return View();
 }
```

with this code using i have done login very well. but now i want login using membership. i have one question here for membership have any dll?

This is my web.config file =>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
 For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please 
 visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration> 
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication3-20170821032922.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication3-20170821032922;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
 <appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
  <system.web>
<authentication mode="None" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
 </system.web>
 <system.webServer>
   <modules>
    <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
   </modules>
 </system.webServer>
 <runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
 </runtime>
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

any one have the idea how can do that please let me know.

Comment: You just create a MVC project in Visual studio. There select authentication type before create project. From there you can extract all the things you need.

Comment: @PowerStar but in mvc already project is created before one year now i want to change login module so how can create new project. i want to change in existing code

Comment: I am saying you just create a standalone poc project.  From there you can understand membership in mvc. There you can see OWIN dll for identity membership

Comment: ok i will do and then after i need to same code doing in this project??

Comment: Yes similar to that

Comment: First try to understand about identity membership.

Answer (score -1):

apply the link below, it will be helpfull to integrate login operation;

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset